# Python & SnakeSQL - raise lock.LockError('Lock no longer valid.') ERROR

Tags: sql, python-2.7

I am trying to run a python script (createdb.py) which has DB operations from my main python script (app.py) but having the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 236, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 227, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 409, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 384, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "D:\Python\virtualenvs\new4\textweb\bin\app.py", line 16, in GET
    createdb.createTables()
  File "D:\Python\virtualenvs\new4\textweb\bin\createdb.py", line 9, in createTables
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE table (dateColumn Date, numberColumn Integer)")
  File "D:\Python\virtualenvs\new4\textweb\bin\SnakeSQL\driver\base.py", line 1548, in execute
    self.info = self.connection._create(parsedSQL['table'], parsedSQL['columns'], parameters)
  File "D:\Python\virtualenvs\new4\textweb\bin\SnakeSQL\driver\base.py", line 993, in _create
    self._insertRowInColTypes(table)
  File "D:\Python\virtualenvs\new4\textweb\bin\SnakeSQL\driver\base.py", line 632, in _insertRowInColTypes
    ], types= ['String','String','String','Bool','Bool','Bool','Text','Text','Integer']
  File "D:\Python\virtualenvs\new4\textweb\bin\SnakeSQL\driver\dbm.py", line 61, in _insertRow
    self.tables[table].file[str(primaryKey)] = str(values)
  File "D:\Python\virtualenvs\new4\textweb\bin\SnakeSQL\external\lockdbm.py", line 50, in __setitem__
    raise lock.LockError('Lock no longer valid.')
LockError: Lock no longer valid.
```

Here is my createdb.py code;

```
import SnakeSQL

connection = SnakeSQL.connect(database='test', autoCreate=True)
connection = SnakeSQL.connect(database='test')

cursor = connection.cursor()

def createTables():
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE table (dateColumn Date, numberColumn Integer)")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2003-11-8', 3)")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2004-11-8', 4)")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2005-11-8', 5)")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2006-11-8', 6)")


def select():
    selectResult = cursor.execute("SELECT dateColumn FROM table WHERE numberColumn = 3")
    return selectResult

if __name__ == "__main__":
    createTables()
```

and here is my app.py code;

```
import web
import SnakeSQL
import createdb

render = web.template.render('templates/')

connection = SnakeSQL.connect(database='test')
cursor = connection.cursor()

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        createdb.createTables()
        result = createdb.select()
        return render.index(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

I couldn't find out why I am having this error. Can you please share your knowledge for solving this problem?

Comment: Haven't used SnakeSql, but I can't imagine you'd ever want to make a `cursor` a module-level constant.  Try  creating the cursor(s) inside your methods.

Comment: Actually I already tried it but then I got another error like there is no global constant for cursor. That is why I moved it outside of the function.

Comment: Yes, you need to either create a cursor in each function that uses it, or pass it in as a parameter.  (That part really has nothing to do with SnakeSQL - it's just how functions in Python, and pretty much every other programming language work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the [SnakeSQL docs](http://pythonweb.org/projects/snakesql/doc/current/html/snakesql.html#SECTION000610000000000000000) appear to be from 2004, the actual code was last updated in 2009, and the author states that the project is no longer maintained.  You may want to consider using something still actively maintained instead.

The [docs](http://pythonweb.org/projects/snakesql/doc/current/html/snakesql.html#SECTION000420000000000000000) also mention:

> In theory, one of the processes accessing the database could get stuck in an infinite loop and not release the lock on the database to allow other users to access it. After a period of 2 seconds, if the process with the current lock on the database doesn't access it, the lock will be released and another process can obtain a lock. The first process will itself have to wait to obtain a lock.

Looking at your traceback, I'll make an educated guess that since you put the cursor at module level (which again, you probably don't want to do), it created the cursor when the module was first imported, then by the time your program actually ran the `createTables` function, more than 2 seconds had elapsed, and it has given up the lock.

Try moving the line to create your cursor inside your methods:

```
def createTables():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE table (dateColumn Date, numberColumn Integer)")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2003-11-8', 3)")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2004-11-8', 4)")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2005-11-8', 5)")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2006-11-8', 6)")


def select():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    selectResult = cursor.execute("SELECT dateColumn FROM table WHERE numberColumn = 3")
    return selectResult
```

(and do the same in your app.py code).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me. After your suggestion, I am also considering to change my DB choice.